# Postman collection run via GitHub action stopped working

Tags: postman, github-actions, cicd

I've been succesfully running Postman CLI GitHub action until the last week. Following is the Action config:

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Postman CLI
        run: |
          curl -o- "https://dl-cli.pstmn.io/install/linux64.sh" | sh
      - name: Login to Postman CLI
        run: postman login --with-api-key ${{ secrets.POSTMAN_API_KEY }}
      - name: Run API tests
        run: |
          postman collection run "14779683-c20279a2-e01b-42d7-a435-cb45a05d982c" -e "14779683-fb25fdcd-2eee-4e1a-9bc5-5c13edfef1a5" --integration-id "135195-${{ github.run_id }}"
          postman api lint --integration-id 135195-${{ github.run_id }}
```

The API key seems to be valid, as it runs the collection and finished all tests. But since the last week or so, I started to get following message:

```
Postman CLI run data uploaded to Postman Cloud successfully.
You can view the run data in Postman at: https://go.postman.co/workspace/3998f5e5-fd98-4009-8cac-16dbba3f93fc/api/f79c4bd4-cf58-4ff8-9237-2f4a87135b6c/run/14779683-dcbd86b3-9124-4295-b476-03a1d7ab6768
Error: Couldn't find the Postman config file in the current directory.
Try re-integrating this folder with your Postman API. https://go.pstmn.io/v10-git-local-docs
```

Does someone know what is missing, something have changed with the Postman CLI perhaps?

Comment: Do you have the postman config file postman.json or postman.yaml in the same directory and pushed to GitHub?

Comment: I don't have postman config file, it worked fine without it up to last week... What is postman config file? The collection actually runs, the error message appears after all tests are done and the results are uploaded to Postman cloud (i can see them in web link)

Comment: @FimaRotter Can you verify once if `postman api lint` command is present in your Actions config? 
If yes, that could be the cause (you could remove it if you don't need it).
If you do need it, you could also share the details on help@getpostman.com and we'll look into it (I currently work at Postman)

Comment: I removed lint for test and the error is still there.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, removing the lint does fix this! Thanks!